# I' am creating the service in Angular with Node.js. Problem with date transferring between the components

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, transfer

I' am creating the service in Angular with Node.js. I have created 2 components and I want to share the data between them. From droplist to cards. With two droplists I search the date in the table and after I creates many buttons with names of Scenarios of the response in the cards component. But the data does not transfer from with routing. There aren't any errors in console.

Project on stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/github/ShimolinNik/LawClinicFrontend

This is my Frontend in Gitlab.
[1]: https://gitlab.unige.ch/thinkdata-pour-la-clinique-de-la-loi/front-end

Droplist component :

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-droplist',
  templateUrl: './droplist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./droplist.component.css']
})
export class DroplistComponent implements OnInit {


  themes = ["Tous les thèmes","Procédure d'asile", "Représentation légale", "Aides financières et matérielles",
            "Hébergement", "Santé", "Famille", "Formation", "Vie courante et voyage",
            "Protection en cas de violences", "Droits face à la police", "Questions spécifiques au Tribunal"];


  mots = ["Tous les mots","admission provisoire","aide d’urgence","aide sociale","AJ","aménagements","appréhension",
          "apprentissage","assistance judiciaire gratuite","assistance juridique","assistant-e social-e","besoins éducatifs particuliers",
          "besoins éducatifs particuliers","centre de la Confédération","classes d’accueil","conseiller-ère-s juridiques",
          "curateur-rice","débouté-e","débouté-e de l'asile","décision d'exécution du renvoi","décision de non-entrée en matière (NEM)",
          "décision de renvoi","décision de renvoi avec délai de départ","décision d’exécution du renvoi","décision NEM","décision NEM Dublin",
          "défense d’office","défense obligatoire","dénonciation","détenu-e","droit d’être entendu-e","École de culture générale (ECG)","école ordinaire",
          "école spécialisée","effet suspensif","enseignement secondaire II","espace Dublin","État Dublin","Haute école spécialisée (HES)",
          "IGS","intérêt supérieur de l’enfant","majeur-e","    mesures de pédagogie spécialisée","mineur-e","Ministère public","moyen de preuve","OCPM","PC",
          "peine pécuniaire","permis B","permis B réfugié-e","permis C","permis F","permis F admission provisoire","permis F réfugié-e","permis L",
          "permis N","personne de confiance","personne lésée","plainte pénale","planning familial","prévenu-e","prime d’assurance-maladie","primes",
          "principe de proportionnalité","procédure accélérée","procédure de poursuite","procédure Dublin","procédure étendue","procédure pénale","procès-verbal (PV)",
          "recours","réfugié-e","regroupement familial","régularisation","représentant-e juridique","représentant-e légal-e","sans statut légal",
          "secondaire I","sexe légal","subside","témoin","Tribunal des mineur-e-s","tuteur-rice","université","victime","vie familiale","vie familiale existante"];
  

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,private router:Router) { }

  selectedTheme:String = "Tous les thèmes";
  selectedMot:String = "Tous les mots";


  onSelect(){
    this.getCartes();
    this.router.navigate(['./cards'], {state:{info:this.information }})
  }
  lasttheme:String="";
  lastmot:String="";

  information:any;

  id = 0;
  getValue(value :any) {
    this.id=value;
    console.log(value);
  }

  getDonnees() {

    this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/sc/"+this.id.toString()).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
  }
 

  getCartes() {
    console.log(this.selectedTheme);
    console.log(this.selectedMot);
    
    // Recherche par tous les thèmes et par tous les mots
    if(this.selectedTheme == "Tous les thèmes" && this.selectedMot == "Tous les mots"){
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/all").subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
      this.lasttheme=this.selectedTheme;
      this.lastmot=this.selectedMot;
    }
    // Recherche par thème
    else if (this.selectedTheme != this.lasttheme && (this.selectedMot=="" || this.selectedMot=="Tous les mots")) {
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000//"+this.selectedTheme).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;console.log(this.information)})
      this.lasttheme=this.selectedTheme;
      this.lastmot=this.selectedMot;
    }
    else if(this.selectedMot == "Tous les mots" && this.selectedTheme == this.lasttheme){
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000//"+this.selectedTheme).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
      this.lastmot=this.selectedMot;
    }
    // Recherche par mot
    else if (this.selectedMot != this.lastmot && (this.selectedTheme == "" || this.selectedTheme == "Tous les thèmes")) {
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/"+this.selectedMot).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
      this.lasttheme=this.selectedTheme;
      this.lastmot=this.selectedMot;
    }
    else if (this.selectedTheme == "Tous les thèmes" && this.selectedMot == this.lastmot){
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/"+this.selectedMot).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
      this.lasttheme=this.selectedTheme;
    }
    //Recherche par mot et par thème
    else if ((this.selectedTheme != this.lasttheme && this.selectedTheme != "Tous les thèmes" &&  this.selectedMot != "" ) || (this.selectedMot != this.lastmot && this.selectedMot!="Tous les mots" && this.selectedTheme !="" )){
      this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/"+this.selectedTheme+"/"+this.selectedMot).subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})
      this.lasttheme=this.selectedTheme;
      this.lastmot=this.selectedMot;
    }
    else {
      console.log(5)

    }
    console.log(this.information)
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:3000/all").subscribe(res => {this.information=res;})

  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Themes</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTheme" (selectionChange)="onSelect()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let theme of themes" [value]="theme">
      {{theme}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selectedTheme}}</p>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Mots-clés</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedMot" (selectionChange)="onSelect()">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let mot of mots" [value]="mot">
      {{mot}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>Your selected mot: {{selectedMot}}</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Cards component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DroplistComponent } from '../droplist/droplist.component';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cards.component.css']
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router:Router) {
    this.info = this.router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras.state?.info;
  }

  info;

ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

}
```

```html
<button  id ="element.id_Scenario" *ngFor="let element of info" >{{element.Nom_Scenario}}</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Help me please

Comment: Could you make stackblitz example? We can't exactly access your source code.

Comment: I did it. https://stackblitz.com/github/ShimolinNik/LawClinicFrontend

Comment: There is no data in router state because `information` is undefined in droplist component when you use `router.navigate`. You first need to wait for API call to complete before navigating. Also, your whole API call logic could use some refactoring.

Comment: I'm beginner in Angular. So could  You please give me the exact changes ?